# Serenity Framework date time display on column and Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working with Serenety Framework Core 2.0

The issue I have is that the date picker does not include the time.
So I create another field to add the time and included the only Display Format I have been able to make it work. An insert Form.cs looks like this

```
   `using Serenity;
    using Serenity.ComponentModel;
    using Serenity.Data;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using OfficeOpenXml.FormulaParsing.Excel.Functions.DateTime;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


    [FormScript("Default.Events")]
    [BasedOnRow(typeof(Entities.EventsRow), CheckNames = true)]
    public class EventsForm
    {
        [TextAreaEditor(Rows = 3)]
        public String Title { get; set; }
        [TextAreaEditor(Rows = 8)]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        [Serenity.ComponentModel.DisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")]
        public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
        [Serenity.ComponentModel.DisplayFormat("HH:mm")]
        public Time Time { get; set; }`
```

However nor the date picker or the time field show a time picker for lack of a better term.

I would like to have the time show either with the date picker or in its own filed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provide by Leo over Serenity Whatsup group. Simply to use DateTimeEditor

```
        [DateTimeEditor(IntervalMinutes =1)]
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
```

[image]